# Outlier Detection and Removal

Tags: outliers, data-preprocessing

I am reading a paper on wind power forecasting and the authors present a plot of the data before outliers are removed and a plot after. However, they don't actually say what method was employed to remove the outliers. I was hoping someone might offer some guesses or hints on how one would go about obtaining plot (b) from plot (a).[image]

Comment: Whatever we guess, it's the authors' job to properly explain what they're doing, so if this is not explained, it doesn't reflect well on what's in the paper. (Of course they could just look at the first plot and then throw away whatever they don't like...)

Comment: Agreed. I asked for clarification but haven't received a response so I figured I would see if I could find a reasonable approach myself. So far my efforts have come up empty so I am asking here.

Comment: Is there a reason for the time series tag?  I don't see any time series aspect here.

Answer (score 0):

> the authors ... don't actually say what method was employed to remove the outliers.

You didn't cite the authors' paper :-(

---

A significant number of readings produce zero power.
This likely corresponds to scheduled or unscheduled downtime
where the turbine is disconnected from the grid
or otherwise not generating power on a windy day.

Most of the other filtered readings correspond
to low-efficiency operation.
This could be caused by wind direction being off-axis
from the turbine, deliberate use of a mechanical brake,
poorly maintained lubrication, and similar mechanical issues.

Given that additionally a small number of outliers are discarded
from the "unusually high efficiency" side,
there's a decent chance the authors computed standard deviation
and retained just those points that are within about 2 sigma
of a fitted curve.
This would explain filtering of the "zero power" outliers, as well.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I actually started with something similar to what you are suggesting (2 sigma or similar) but it kept giving me weird results. I will revisit and see if I can make it work now that I have some assurance that it is a valid approach.

Comment: Clearly the 0 power data were removed. That could be from something like what JH suggested, but it also might be that those are data entry errors.

Comment: A very close look dissuaded me from offering this suggestion, because a lower cutoff based on conditional SD that cleans the graph so neatly near the bottom left would not leave so many low stragglers in the middle.  I suspect something a little more sophisticated might have happened, such as removing outlying residuals from some kind of robust logistic regression.  But without seeing the original paper it seems all we can do is speculate.

Comment: Sorry, here is the paper: https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/16/6/2688